# NameError: name "IntegerField" is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I'm new to Django and I am receiing this error and I am not sure why. Can anyone assist me?

Error message:
I entered "python3 manage.py makemigrations" in the shell, please look at the hyperlink to view the
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKh4Z.png)

Comment: Please share the models. Share the *code*, not *images* of code.

Answer (score 3):

In order to use an `IntegerField`, you need to import it. For example:

```
from django.db.models import IntegerField, Model

class Flight(Model):
    duration = IntegerField()
```

or if you use the `models` module, access is through `models`:

```
from django.db import models

class Flight(models.Model):
    duration = models.IntegerField()
```

Note that Django has a [**`DurationField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#durationfield) which is wrapped to a `timedelta`. Depending on the database you use, behind the curtains it will use an `INTERVAL`, or a `BIGINT`.